# Jenkins fails to build Job while running in Docker container ( Chrome failed to start: crashed )

Tags: docker, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

So I am trying to run at least one test which uses selenium and chromedriver.

I have also setup xvfb so that I can run these tests in a headless manner. I have the xvfb jenkins plugin installed and it is working correctly.

So.. here's what my Dockerfile looks like:

> **Dockerfile**

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest
ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
ENV CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG /var/jenkins_home/casc.yaml
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
COPY casc.yaml /var/jenkins_home/casc.yaml
USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install wget \
&& apt-get install -y nodejs && apt-get install -y npm \

# The current stable google-chrome version is 93 and so ill be installing version 93 for chromedriver
&& wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb \
&& apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb \
&& wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/93.0.4577.15/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
&& unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
USER jenkins
```

Iv basically installed most of what is needed, I have switched back and forth with google-chrome and chromedriver versions always keeping them at supported versions... but that definitely does not seem to be my issue, until this:

> **This is my console output on Jenkins**

```
[0-0] 2021-09-01T11:58:00.522Z WARN webdriver: Request failed due to unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600233 (523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d),platform=Linux 5.10.47-linuxkit x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 551 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time: '2018-11-06T11:58:47'
System info: host: '06baf4ed587a', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.47-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.12'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
[0-0] 2021-09-01T11:58:00.523Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 1/3
[0-0] 2021-09-01T11:58:00.523Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session
[0-0] 2021-09-01T11:58:00.523Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
  capabilities: {
    alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': [Object] },
    firstMatch: [ {} ]
  },
  desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': { args: [Array] } }
}
```

and linked it to this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2473 which is a reoccurring issue with Docker, and there are workaround flags that might help in that link, I'm just not sure how to implement it into my environment, thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to **re-install** the chrome again, chrome has crashed, that is why chrome driver was unable to start the chrome.

Steps to install:

1. curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash
2. google-chrome --version && which google-chrome

Comment: Hi Jayanth Bala, just out of curiosity, do you know how to implement the flags 
"--no-sandbox" and "--disable-dev-shm-usage", where exactly do I place them since i'm using a Docker container

Comment: Hmmm, still doesn't seen to work.. maybe I need to add those 2 flags, but i'm not exactly sure where to..

Comment: Pass the flags when starting the driver in selenium.

Comment: I usally provide that in the chrome initialization, like in the options

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--window-position=0,0"));
                options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--window-size=1840,1080"));
                options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--no-sandbox"));
                options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--disable-dev-shm-usage"));
                options.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--disable-gpu"));